# Нужна помощь в понимании ООП: на входе html, а на выходе лист с данными

Tags: python, ооп

Пишу парсер, который собирает данные в базу, хочу создать класс, который на входе принимает html собирает данные со страницы, а на выходе выдает лист с данными.

Можно небольшой пример такого класса и пример его вызова? Можно всего лишь два метода.

И вообще правильно ли осмыслил необходимость классов?

Comment: Зачем вам класс? Вы собираетесь его использовать где-то еще?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону sqlalchemy -- эта библиотека позволяет с помощью классов описать таблицы базы. Вы сможете написать класс, описывающий строку таблицы и в него включить парсинг, чтобы и распарсил, заполнив свои поля и потом все это сразу сохранить в базу. Кроме того, алхимия умеет работать с разными базами, вам не придется sql использовать (конечно можно руками писать, но не обязательно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Parser
{
  protected $html;

  public function __construct($html)
  {
    $this->html = $html;
  }

  public function getData()
  {
    $data = $this->html;
    // Тут html превращается в данные
    return $data;
  }

$parser = new Parser($html);

$data = $parser->getData();
```

Необходимость классов раскрывается, если есть, например, два метода получения данных. Например, на входе html, а на выходе можно получить текст (getText) или json (getJson). Или наоборот, на входе имеем либо html, либо еще что-то, а на выходе данные в нужном формате.

Comment: ну хоть на Php, но суть в принципе ясна. Нет, мне нужно из дивов выдергивать данные и записывать их в базу.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил python. Но вообще да, тут язык особой роли не играет.

Comment: Еще ООП полезно, когда есть некий абстрактный парсер, который на входе имеет HTML, а на выходе нужный формат. В классе есть метод превращения HTML в данные. Этот класс можно наследовать, изменяя метод обработки html в данные для другого источника.

Answer (score 1):

В Питоне для вашей задачи достаточно функции:

```
def get_data(html):
    # extract data...
    return data
```

Реализована эта функция будет с помощью объектов таких как  подкласса `html.parser.HTMLParser` ([пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/9903390)) или более удобного API `bs4.BeautifulSoup` ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14338006/4279)).